# how to keep state when on/off in switch button below images

Tags: switch-statement

http://s107.photobucket.com/user/nguyenduydat274/media/onoff.png.html

[image]

On into Off: keep state (on/off) and disable listview

Off into On : keep sate (on/off) and enable lliseview.

Comment: Where are you getting the movies from ? Do you have them stored locally anywhere in the app ?

Comment: yes, I get the movies from api and stored in on locally. Thanks.

Comment: If you have them stored locally in a database you can just add another field which stores the state of the button. To, enable or disable an item, you'll need to return false from `isEnabled(int position)` method in the adapter.

Comment: i have still completed yet. I have 2 class UserSettingFragment (http://www.fshare.vn/file/HMDP9RTJ16K3)  and UserSettingAdapter (http://www.fshare.vn/file/1DGX29QQ9OFT) . Please help me.

Comment: What is the exact problem ? What is not working ?

Comment: I want when On into Off: keep state (on/off) and disable listview

Off into On : keep sate (on/off) and enable lliseview. But not correct.

Comment: Let see picture: When On -> Off: Disable listview and Birdman (On), Blackhat( Off) and Into The Woods ( On) , but both of them is OFF and not disable...

Comment: Do you mean list view or list item ? list view means the whole list, list item means one view such as the row containing Blackhat.

Comment: when On -> Off , let me pictucre http://s107.photobucket.com/user/nguyenduydat274/media/2-1.png.html -> it's not correct , it should keep status on/off of every item and disable listview, and Off -> On, too. (http://s107.photobucket.com/user/nguyenduydat274/media/3-2.png.html -> it's not correct)

Answer (score 0):

I'll add small code from what I have understood. The idea is when you turn off / on the 'all saved movies' button, the list view should get enabled and disabled and also maintain the state of the particular movie.

```
public class UserSettingsMoviesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Stores if the list is enabled or disabled. You need to update this 
    // value when the 'All saved movies' button is turned on or off. 
    private Boolean isListEnabled;

    // This list will store if the movie is checked.
    private List < Boolean > mArrChecked;

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        if (isListEnabled) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ...

        boolean isChecked = mArrChecked.get(position);
        swOnOff.setChecked(isChecked);

        swOnOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {@Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                mArrChecked.set(currentPos, isChecked);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        ...
    }
}
```

Now, to enable or disable the whole list you'll need to change the value of `isListEnabled` variable. If it returns false, `isEnabled()` will return false for each item and all items will be disabled by the list view but the state will remain. Make sure you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after updating the value of `isListEnabled`.